# Cypress.io pause() function

Tags: cypress

Pause() before Assert function

If I write pause() before my assert function which I'm trying to validate, It's executing the assert function first and then the pause function is executing, what can I do to solve this?Is there any other way to pause before assert()?

[Cypress runner image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WDih.png)

[Code Level image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pYYC.png)

Answer (score 3):

The code in your test is not running in the order you presume.

`cy` commands are running in a queue and do not execute immediately. However, javascript lines like `assert()` *are* executed immediately.

Unless you tell Cypress to also run them on the queue,

```js
cy.pause()
cy.then(() => assert(...))  // executes the callback on the queue
```